# Loss in mass due to energy decrease

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, mass-energy

As an object cools down it looses energy. As $E=mc^2$ I would also assume this would correspond to a decrease in the mass of the object. When the energy is released from the substance this corresponds to a decrease in the mass. Does the energy that is lost have mass?

Another similar question is when they say the sun looses mass every minute, where does this mass go? Photons are released, I would assume that these carry the mass away but most books say photons are massless

I have an issue when reading around this topic. Most sources say mass is converted into energy and I assume vice versa although others say this is not true which seems to make sense to me.

I am under the impression that when an object moves it has more kinetic energy and its relativistic mass increases. If the energy was converted to mass as some suggest it wouldnt have kinetic energy any more it would have mass instead. It seems more logical that it has kinetic energy due to its movement and this energy has mass. However I am aware that the sources say energy has no mass

Comment: "Relativistic mass" is an abandoned concept, and no longer widely accepted. Mass is _invariant_.

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational and inertial mass, that is, the mass you learn about in most undergraduate and all high school classes, is the m in $E=mc^2$. Modern physicists find it more convenient to replace m in all the undergraduate and high school senses like gravity, force, inertia, and $E=mc^2$, with $m+U/c^2 + T/ c^2$ where U is internal energy (heat, chemical, nuclear, gravitational,etc) and T is kinetic energy of the object as a whole. This lets mass be an invariant. Same physics, different terminology.

So in the common use sense of mass as inertia and gravitational attraction: yes, changes in kinetic energy, heat, nuclear potential energy, and so on have corresponding changes in mass.

In the esoteric (unless you’re a physicist) sense meant by modern physicists, no, changes in energy are just changes in energy… and changes in energy change inertia and gravity.

The sun also loses some mass in solar wind: high speed hydrogen in the atmosphere of the sun is pushed away from the sun by the radiation pressure of sunlight, towards the outer reaches of the solar system.

Answer (score -1):

> As an object cools down it looses energy. As E=mc2

> I would also assume this would correspond to a decrease in the mass of the object. When the energy is released from the substance this corresponds to a decrease in the mass. Does the energy that is lost have mass?

Sure. It has rest mass: $(total\_energy - kinetic\_energy) / c^2.$ Here kinetic energy means kinetic energy of linear motion.

A light beam has lot of linear kinetic energy, so its mass is low.
An expanding light sphere has not much linear kinetic energy, so its mass is "large". It's $E/c^2$ if the gas has zero linear kinetic energy.

> Another similar question is when they say the sun looses mass every minute, where does this mass go? Photons are released, I would assume that these carry the mass away but most books say photons are massless

The gas of massless photons around the sun has mass $E/c^2$, if the gas has zero linear kinetic energy.

> I have an issue when reading around this topic. Most sources say mass is converted into energy and I assume vice versa although others say this is not true which seems to make sense to me.

> I am under the impression that when an object moves it has more kinetic energy and its relativistic mass increases. If the energy was converted to mass as some suggest it wouldnt have kinetic energy any more it would have mass instead. It seems more logical that it has kinetic energy due to its movement and this energy has mass. However I am aware that the sources say energy has no mass

So now we discuss relativistic mass. Which is:
$total\_energy/c^2$
or:
$kinetic\_energy/c^2 + non\_kinetic\_energy/c^2$

So linear kinetic energy has relativistic mass, while it does not have mass. We can clearly see that in the formulas. Here too kinetic energy means kinetic energy of linear motion.

So, photon gas without linear kinetic energy has mass. When said gas accelerates itself so that it gains linear kinetic energy, it loses mass. As the speed of the gas approaches c, the mass of the gas approaches zero.